# How to check if date falls in a time frame of 3 years from date and 5 years

Tags: ruby

My main problem is how would you write the "3 years/ 5 years"  I have the date which is the **expiry_date**. I need to know if this **date** is between 3 and 5 years old.
Hope the question makes sense **:)**

```
if expiry_date > 3 years && expiry_date < 5 years
```

The `expiry_date` is just a `Date` format

Comment: _"between 3 and 5 years old"_ – do you want to take the current day and month into account (i.e. 2017-09-13 to 2019-09-13) or just the year (i.e. anything from beginning of 2017 to end of 2019)?

Comment: I would need the current day and month

Comment: Japie, when asked for clarification it's best to respond by editing the question rather than elaborating in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ActiveSupport gem excluding begin and end

```
require "active_support/core_ext/integer/time"

expiry_date < 3.years.ago && expiry_date > 5.years.ago
```

If you need to include begin and end of this range

```
(5.years.ago..3.years.ago).include?(expiry_date)
expiry_date.between?(5.years.ago, 3.years.ago)
```

There is also `in?` method in ActiveSupport

```
expiry_date.in?(5.years.ago..3.years.ago)
```

Answer (score 4):

Just Ruby (so no ActiveSupport):

```
require 'date'

today = Date.today
a_date = Date.new(2019,1,1)
p a_date.between?(today.prev_year(5), today.prev_year(3)) # => true
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ruby [cover?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Range.html#method-i-cover-3F) method with ActiveSupport gem to validate the range:

```
require "active_support/core_ext/integer/time"

(5.years.ago..3.years.ago).cover?(expiry_date)
```

Comment: or `expiry_date.between?(5.years.ago, 3.years.ago)`

Comment: Yes, that works as well.

Comment: OP need `>` and `<`, not `>=` and `<=`